# Why does the method not get called as an asynchronous Task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have this code:

```
private async void WaitAnyAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var start = new Task(() => { StartAll("Starter"); } );

    textBox1.Text += "Before" + Environment.NewLine;
    start.Start();
    textBox1.Text += "End" + Environment.NewLine;
}

private async Task StartAll(string mssg)
{
    textBox1.Text += mssg + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Which outputs this (in text TextBox control):

```
Before
End
```

But I'm sure it should be outputting this:

```
Before
End
Starter
```

Why is it not doing that?

Comment: Does this compile? You are not awaiting any of the tasks.

Comment: Why are you using `async` at all here? You're not awaiting anything.

Comment: Don't ever use the task constructor.

Comment: It does compile - it is a Button click handler. I'm not awaiting any Tasks and I guess that's what I'm doing wrong, but I'm not sure where to put the await. Why is the Task constructor bad? How do I get the Starter message output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private async Task WaitAnyAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var start = Task.Run(() => { StartAll("Starter"); } );

    textBox1.Text += "Before" + Environment.NewLine;
    await start;
    textBox1.Text += "End" + Environment.NewLine;
}

private void StartAll(string mssg)
{
    textBox1.Text += mssg + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Starting a task is best done with `Task.Run` you need to `await` the task to asynchronously wait for its completion. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for some great advice on async-await.

I've also removed the returned `Task` from `StartAll` as an `async` method needs to have an `await` in it and you haven't got any.

Answer (score 0):

Controls in Windows Forms are bound to a specific thread and are not thread safe. Therefore, if you are calling a control's property from a different thread, the task needs to be scheduled properly with the GUI thread. So modify your code slightly to create a task scheduler and run the overloaded version of the Task.Start method as shown below.

```
private async void WaitAnyAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var start = new Task(() => { StartAll("Starter"); });    
    textBox1.Text += "Before";
    var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();  
    start.Start(scheduler);                         
    textBox1.Text += "End";
}
```